# Stepper motors: feedback to detect successful step?

Tags: driver, stepper-motor, feedback

Is it possible to have a stepper motor driver circuit detect if the motor has successfully stepped, ie not stalled, or stepped too quickly? (Not microstepping).

Comment: Not easily, and if you are going to go to that trouble you might as well use a proper encoder, and then a servomotor with a closed loop driver.  Stepper motors are an inferior solution - they get used when the let you keep things simple, but once you give up on that there are better choices.

Comment: I second what Chris said. It can be done, it just isn't practical. Your first option is to make sure that you never miss a step - and that simply means keeping enough margin in your design. If you can't do that, then it's time to move up to a servo.

Comment: I disagree with both above.  Adding encoder feedback to a stepper-motor system is fairly common practice.

Comment: @DwayneReid - Entirely true, but my reading of the OP is that he's asking for a modification of a stepper drive circuit, not adding an entire new sensor/conditioner/logic function.

Comment: @DwayneReid - My interpretation was the same as Beast's - He was looking for something electronic, like monitoring back-EMF. But I also don't believe encoders on steppers is cost effective anymore - it's cheaper to go with a DC motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, except maybe some very fiddly, exotic circuit for a particular motor. Not worth it. There are a growing number of stepper motors available with shaft encoders. And even stepper motor drivers with built-in feedback sensing (from a shaft encoder) to make the whole solution turn-key.